# Which package should I download to compile C++0x code

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

OS is Ubuntu 10.04.
I need to compile some C++ code with `-std=c++0x` flag. But compiling doesn't work because I need 4.6.1 version.
Now, when I go to Gnu's ftp, I see two different packages:

```
gcc-4.6.1   
gcc-g++-4.6.1
```

Knowing that I need to compile C++0x code, which one should I download, and how do I install it/them?
I already installed these libraries (gmp, mpc and mpfr).

Comment: You'll likely need both of those and then some. Grab `gcc-g++` first. Then see what it says it needs in order to install.

Comment: GCC originally meant GNU C Compiler. Now it's GNU Compiler Collection. The g++ program is in fact the C++ compiler part of it. The idea is that if you for example only want to use C++ compiler, you don't have to download for example the  Ada compiler which is also part of GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I googled around for a few minutes, and found quite a few things, mostly involving compiling for some iPhone stuff. It appears that you just need to use [GCC 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html). As said in the comments, you will likely need both though, since it is still experimental.